# Conversion of potential energy in other forms of energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy

Can potential energy be directly converted into other forms of energy rather than first converting to kinetic energy then to other forms of energy

Answer (score 3):

If you think about it in terms of classical mechanics, then on a microscopic level there is only potential and kinetic energy, as every point particle is within the potential that is established by all other point particles in the universe.
The distinction between kinetic and potential energy only arises because both position and momentum variables for every degree of freedom are needed for a complete description of the physical state (i.e. phase space), where potential energy is associated with positional variables and kinetic energy with momentum variables. Every other kind of energy is basically a label for special kinds of potentials (e.g. nuclear energy), a distinction of what degree of freedom is involved (e.g. mechanical vs electrical) or how the trajectory within phase space is structured (e.g. thermal energy associated with the random part of the trajectory of a multi particle system).

The trajectory of a dynamical system through phase space is continuos and always involves position and momentum, so conversion between kinetic and potential energy is inevitable. However, since thermal energy is a mix of kinetic and potential energy it could be said that potential energy can be directly conversed to it, so the answer to your question should be yes.

Comment: Can potential energy be converted into other potential energies